# sagetex with breqn ? break line sagetex equations

Tags: equations, line-breaking, breqn, sagetex

When using sagetex, it often produces very long equations that are not visible anymore because they go over the page width.

How to fix that?

I could work around it by loading the .sagetex.sage into a sage session, then produce latex code with latex(functionname) and then break this code manually but it would be against the spirit of sagetex.

I tried the breqn environment but it does not work, i.e.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sagetex}
\usepackage{breqn}

\begin{document}

\begin{sagesilent}
var('d,epsilon,mu,z,M,e,m')
delta =  (1-z)*( gamma(2-d/2)/( (1-z)^2*m^2+z*M^2 )^(2-d/2) *(2-epsilon)^2/2 + gamma(3-d/2)/( (1-z)^2*m^2+z*M^2 )^(3-d/2) * ( 2*(1-4*z+z^2)-epsilon*(1-z)^2 )*m^2  )
 \end{sagesilent}

\begin{dmath}
\sage{delta.diff(m).subs(m==mu)}
\end{dmath}

\end{document}
```

produces an equation that has no line breaks. I cannot use environments like split or align to fix it because I cannot directly modify the latex code, or, if I would via sage, it would not be convenient anymore to use sagetex.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you!

For the comment I also add the generated latex-Code below. Thanks for the comment!

```
\frac{1}{2} \, {\left(\frac{2 \, {\left(\epsilon {\left(z - 1\right)}^{2} - 2 \, z^{2} + 8 \, z - 2\right)} {\left(\mu^{2} {\left(z - 1\right)}^{2} + M^{2} z\right)}^{-\frac{1}{2} \, d + 2} {\left(d - 6\right)} \mu^{3} {\left(z - 1\right)}^{2} \Gamma\left(-\frac{1}{2} \, d + 3\right)}{{\left({\left(\mu^{2} {\left(z - 1\right)}^{2} + M^{2} z\right)}^{-\frac{1}{2} \, d + 3}\right)}^{2}} - \frac{{\left(\mu^{2} {\left(z - 1\right)}^{2} + M^{2} z\right)}^{-\frac{1}{2} \, d + 1} {\left(d - 4\right)} {\left(\epsilon - 2\right)}^{2} \mu {\left(z - 1\right)}^{2} \Gamma\left(-\frac{1}{2} \, d + 2\right)}{{\left({\left(\mu^{2} {\left(z - 1\right)}^{2} + M^{2} z\right)}^{-\frac{1}{2} \, d + 2}\right)}^{2}} + \frac{4 \, {\left(\epsilon {\left(z - 1\right)}^{2} - 2 \, z^{2} + 8 \, z - 2\right)} \mu \Gamma\left(-\frac{1}{2} \, d + 3\right)}{{\left(\mu^{2} {\left(z - 1\right)}^{2} + M^{2} z\right)}^{-\frac{1}{2} \, d + 3}}\right)} {\left(z - 1\right)}
```

Comment: is it possible to also show the generated latex that gets passed to latex, for those of us who haven't got sage(tex) installed? had to debug otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. 
I know now that the reason for the non line break is that the generated latex code from sage contains a lot of {\left and \right)} that are interpreted by dmath as "please dont break the line here".
But I cant write any macro in Latex that removes "{"  because they are themselves trigger parameters... So the deletion of { and } should come from sage before handing the code to latex. Any suggestions on how to do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is not with the `\left...\right` constructs, `breqn` can break these, but stems from the fractions `\frac` which `breqn` can not split up.  Compare the following:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{breqn}

\begin{document}

\begin{dmath}
  \frac{1}{2} \, {\left(\frac{2 \, {\left(\epsilon {\left(z -
        1\right)}^{2} - 2 \, z^{2} + 8 \, z - 2\right)} {\left(\mu^{2}
      {\left(z - 1\right)}^{2} + M^{2} z\right)}^{-\frac{1}{2} \, d +
    2} {\left(d - 6\right)} \mu^{3} {\left(z - 1\right)}^{2}
    \Gamma\left(-\frac{1}{2} \, d + 3\right)}{{\left({\left(\mu^{2}
        {\left(z - 1\right)}^{2} + M^{2} z\right)}^{-\frac{1}{2} \, d
      + 3}\right)}^{2}} - \frac{{\left(\mu^{2} {\left(z -
        1\right)}^{2} + M^{2} z\right)}^{-\frac{1}{2} \, d + 1}
    {\left(d - 4\right)} {\left(\epsilon - 2\right)}^{2} \mu {\left(z
      - 1\right)}^{2} \Gamma\left(-\frac{1}{2} \, d +
      2\right)}{{\left({\left(\mu^{2} {\left(z - 1\right)}^{2} + M^{2}
        z\right)}^{-\frac{1}{2} \, d + 2}\right)}^{2}} + \frac{4 \,
    {\left(\epsilon {\left(z - 1\right)}^{2} - 2 \, z^{2} + 8 \, z -
      2\right)} \mu \Gamma\left(-\frac{1}{2} \, d +
      3\right)}{{\left(\mu^{2} {\left(z - 1\right)}^{2} + M^{2}
      z\right)}^{-\frac{1}{2} \, d + 3}}\right)} {\left(z - 1\right)}
\end{dmath}

\begin{dmath}
  \left( \left(x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\right)
    -
    \left(y+y+y+y+y+y+y+y+y+y+y+y+y+y+y+y+y+y+y+y+y+y+y+y+y+y+y\right)
  \right)
\end{dmath}

\begin{dmath}
  \left( \frac{x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x}{5} -
    \frac{y+y+y+y+y+y+y+y+y+y+y+y+y+y+y+y+y+y+y+y+y+y+y+y+y+y+y}{7}
  \right) 
\end{dmath}

\end{document}
```

Exactly why your example (the first one) does not break at the minus sign, whereas equation (3) does, is not clear to me.  However, the `breqn` package is alpha code and has many open issues.